# Python interface to Haskell library

Tags: python, haskell, interface, subprocess, ghci

I would like to have a Python interface to a Haskell library. The library uses non-standard/user-made types so they cannot be bound to C types - so I'm not sure FFI would work.

My attempt so far consists of running GHCI as a subprocess then passing code as input and parsing the output:

```
# my current setup
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
proc = Popen(["ghci", "some_haskel_file.hs"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

# clear initial output of GHCI
for _ in range(7): proc.stdout.readline()

# this next part may be repeated multiple times
proc.stdin.write(some_haskell_code)
proc.stdin.flush()
output = proc.stdout.readline()
```

I want `output` to contain both the output and any error messages. But I can't get my code to reliable get the output from GHCI.

Here is an example of where the `.readline` method is blocking even though input has been given:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
>>> proc = Popen(["ghci", "Session.hs"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
>>> for _ in range(7): proc.stdout.readline()
...
b'GHCi, version 8.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help\r\n'
b'[1 of 5] Compiling Classes          ( Classes.hs, interpreted )\r\n'
b'[2 of 5] Compiling Functions        ( Functions.hs, interpreted )\r\n'
b'[3 of 5] Compiling Rule             ( Rule.hs, interpreted )\r\n'
b'[4 of 5] Compiling Graph            ( Graph.hs, interpreted )\r\n'
b'[5 of 5] Compiling Main             ( Session.hs, interpreted )\r\n'
b'Ok, five modules loaded.\r\n'
>>> proc.stdin.write("completeGraph 3".encode('utf-8'))
15
>>> proc.stdin.flush()
>>> output = proc.stdout.readline()
|
```

Also, GHCI wants input before sending the prompt `*Main>` to stdout as the following is blocking:

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
>>> proc = Popen(["ghci", "Session.hs"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
>>> for _ in range(8): proc.stdout.readline()
...
b'GHCi, version 8.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help\r\n'
b'[1 of 5] Compiling Classes          ( Classes.hs, interpreted )\r\n'
b'[2 of 5] Compiling Functions        ( Functions.hs, interpreted )\r\n'
b'[3 of 5] Compiling Rule             ( Rule.hs, interpreted )\r\n'
b'[4 of 5] Compiling Graph            ( Graph.hs, interpreted )\r\n'
b'[5 of 5] Compiling Main             ( Session.hs, interpreted )\r\n'
b'Ok, five modules loaded.\r\n'
|
```

Is there another approach that would prove more successful?

Comment: You can interface a Python module to C or most other languages without any need to marshall data back and forth. All you need is an ability to call a foreign function and pass a foreign pointer to it, and you have FFI.

Comment: Take a look at [call-haskell-from-anything](https://github.com/nh2/call-haskell-from-anything). It implements an FFI with function arguments and return values serialized using MessagePack. The repo has an example calling Haskell from Python.

Answer (score 3):

Piping through GHCI seems impossibly fragile. If the library's API currently is not amenable to FFI, I would suggest writing another (Haskell) library that wraps it and provides an API more suitable to you. Then call it through Python's FFI, not through a GHCI pipe. Roundtripping through text is never going to be much fun.

Comment: Would this allow direct access to the type constructors defined in the Haskell library (from Python)? Or can Haskell code using GHC API to execute Haskell code be called through Python's FFI?